# jquery if statement for div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

So I have an HTML table that populates based on a mysql query. It is contained within:

```
<div id="punchclock" class="timecard">
```

And I have the following jQuery script which calculates the totals of the times entered into the HTML table. However, it is repeating the "Total:" line of the script in the header (a separate div) and the table I want. Is there a way to ensure the code only outputs to the desired div?

```
$('table').each(function(){
  var tr = {};
  $(this).find('tr').each(function(){
    var key = $(this).find('td.job_code').text();
    var val1 = toSeconds($(this).find('td.hrs').text());
    //var val = +$(this).find('td.hrs').text().split(':')[0];
    if(tr[key]){
      tr[key]+=val1;
    }else{
      tr[key]=val1; 
    } 
   });

  $(this).append(function(){
    var tfoot = $('<tfoot/>', {
    html: addRows(tr)
   });
   return tfoot;
  });
});
```

I believe the issue lies with the tfoot return statement as it is returning it to the header div and my table div. As always, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the rest of your HTML? I believe your problem is naming conventions and using `$('table')`

Comment: This line looks suspect: `addRows(tr)`. What does `addRows` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select only the table in the div you have defined:

```
$('#punchclock table').each....
```

Your current code will run for every table on the page, and it sounds like you have multiple tables. By selecting `#punchclock table`, it only uses the tables inside `#punchclock`.

If you want to run this for only one table, it would be better to give that one table an id like `<table id="schedule">`, then get rid of your `each` loop, and select the table directly like `$('table#schedule')`.

Also, this block looks suspect:

```
  $(this).append(function(){
    var tfoot = $('<tfoot/>', {
    html: addRows(tr)
   });
   return tfoot;
  });
```

I don't know what `addRows` does but it does not look necessary. Try this instead:

```
  $(this).append($('<tfoot/>').append(tr));
```

Comment: it only uses the tableS inside #punchclock

Comment: Joe, thank you. The #punchclock table worked for me. I needed the add rows function as it helped printed multiple total lines for me.